# Download xml-file and save it to a text file

Tags: python, xml, request

I'm very new at programming and have a problem. I need to create a Python function that uses the request external module to download an XML-file, and then saves the text of the response to a text file.

So far i've tried this:

```
import requests
def downloading_xml():
   r = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simplexsl.xml')
   print(r.text)
```

But I don't get it quite right. I think my main problem is the last part, I don't know how to save the text of the response to a text file. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. If you want to know more about Python file operations follow this link
[Python I/O](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation)

```
import requests
def downloading_xml():
  r = requests.get('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simplexsl.xml')
  print(r.text)
  with open("filename.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(r.text)
    f.close()
```

Now call the function

```
downloading_xml()
```

Answer (score 0):

To save to a text file you can do something like this:

```
textfile=open("anyname.xml",'w')
textfile.write(r.text)
textfile.close()
```

you may need to include the path to the file as well